# Conditionally add OR condition in query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

The orders table have a few columns, say email, tel and address.

User provides email/tel/address, and any of them can be nil or empty string (**EDITED**).

How to generate an OR query, so if any of the columns match, the record is returned?

The only catch is that if any value provided is nil or empty, that will be ignored instead.

I was able to do the following using Arel:

```
email = params[:email]
tel = params[:tel]
address =  params[:address]

t = Order.arel_table
sq = t[:email].eq(email) if email.present?
sq = sq.or(t[:phone].eq(phone)) if phone.present?
sq = sq.or(t[:phone].eq(address)) if address.present?
Order.where( sq )
```

However it will err if email is nil, because sq will not instantiate.

I want to prevent constructing sql string, and I use Squeel gem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to prevent nil or empty string, I finally got the following:

```
t = Order.arel_table

conditions = [:email, :phone, :address].map{|attr|
  attr_value = params[attr]
  if attr_value.present?
    t[attr].eq(attr_value)
  else
    nil
  end
}.compact

if conditions.empty?
  Order.where('1=0')
else
  Order.where( conditions.inject{|c, cc| c.or(cc).expr} )
end
```

Ugly, but flexible.

Answer (score 2):

you can put

```
Order.where("email=? or tel= ? or address=?", params[:email], params[:tel], params[:address])
```

Comment: To my surprise (duh!) this works for nil values, because in sql `address=NULL` will not fetch null address records.

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether your params are nil or not by [Ick's](http://ick.rubyforge.org/) maybe. So read about Ick gem and follow the steps given there and then you can use it in your case like :

`params[:email].maybe`
`params[:tel].maybe`
`params[:address].maybe`

Hope, this is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a try with

```
where_condition = "true"
where_condition += "OR email = '#{params[:email]}'" if params[:email].present?  
where_condition += "OR tel = '#{params[:tel]}'" if params[:tel].present?
where_condition += "OR address = '#{params[:address]}'" if params[:address].present?

Order.where(where_condition)
```